# Nginx seems to be dropping HTTPS when redirecting to another server

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, https

I have two servers A and B configured using nginx, each with domain `a.domain.com` and `b.domain.com`. The problem with B is that its port 80 is blocked, so I thought I'd reroute all requests, including both port 80 and port 443 traffic for server A to server B, rewriting it to HTTPS in the process. Here's my attempt at it.

**A**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name a.domain.com
  location / {
    return 301 https://b.domain.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name a.domain.com
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate       /* not shown */
  ssl_certificate_key   /* not shown */
  location / {
    return 301 https://b.domain.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

**B**

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name b.domain.com
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate       /* not shown */
  ssl_certificate_key   /* not shown */
  location / {
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://b.domain.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;        # this is to tomcat
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. Directly accessing something like `https://b.domain.com/folder` works, `http://a.domain.com` and `https://a.domain.com` jumps to `https://b.domain.com`, but neither `http://a.domain.com/folder` or `https://a.domain.com/folder` redirects as intended (to `https://b.domain.com/folder`). In the process, as shown in my browser, the HTTPS scheme is dropped; but because server B has no port 80 access the request times out. Something I think is noteworthy is that `a.domain.com` is configured to use a wildcard certificate while `b.domain.com` is configured to use a certificate dedicated to the subdomain.

Help?

Comment: The configuration you've posted looks correct. So something else is going on. Consider showing the _actual_ configuration, including the real domain name(s). [Why we ask for this](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your response. I wasn't aware of the convention; but all `a.domain.com` in the question would be `p.cgs.news` and `b.domain.com` would be `pi.cgs.news`. I've temporarily removed all irrelevant entries in the configuration files on the two servers, and restarted them. The problem persists.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I load `http://p.cgs.news/folder` and get redirected properly to `https://pi.cgs.news/folder/` and see the page containing only the word "Working".

Comment: That's very weird. Thank you for your time, I'll try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Internal DNS match external by chance....

Comment: Are you sure your Tomcat is listening on IPv4 127.0.0.1:8080?

Comment: Was the redirection ever different/wrong in the past? Your browser(s) may have cached it -- and that can differ by URL.

Comment: Looking at OP's current `301`, you can certainly re-post it as an answer @dave_thompson_085.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the ssl offloading:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name b.domain.com
```